# Show that $\gamma$ is a parametrization for the one sheet hyperboloid

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, inverse-function, parametrization, inverse-function-theorem

I'm given $\gamma:(-\pi,\pi)\times \mathbb{R}\to S$ where $S$ is the one-sheet hyperbolid definied by the equation: $$x^2+y^2-z^2=1$$

Such that $\gamma(u,v)=(\cos(u)-v\sin(u),\sin(u)+v\cos(u),v)$.

I'm trying to show that $\gamma$ is a parametrization, I've already shown that $\gamma$ is smooth and its differential map is injective. I'm left to show that $\gamma^{-1}$ is continuous but I can't explicitly calculate it.

I've done some arithmetic and found two candidates which are $(x,y,z)\mapsto (\arctan(\frac{y-zx}{x+zy}),z)$ and $(x,y,z)\mapsto (\arccos(\frac{x+zy}{1+z^2}),z)$ but they wouldn't have the right codomains since $\arctan(\alpha)\in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $\arccos(\alpha)\in (0,\pi)$.

Is there a way to show continuity of $\gamma^{-1}$ without explicitly calculating it? I've thought using the inverse function theorem but the differential map at a point $p$ is given by a $3\times2$ matrix so how can it be a local isomorphism?

Moreover I think the parametrization would be missing the point $(-1,0,0)$ I can fix this by adding another parametrization but if we add $\pi$ this wouldn't happen, we can't do this since $(-\pi,\pi]$ isn't open in the usual topology. Is there a smarter way to fix the parametrization without adding one?

Comment: Try $(x,y,z) \rightarrow (sign(y-zx) \arccos(\frac{x+zy}{1+z^2}), z)$.  This is an explicit inverse, you just need to prove continuity along $y=zx$.

Comment: You don't need to show anything more except that the map is injective (which is not too hard). The inverse function theorem implies that if the differential is bijective between tangent spaces, then the map is a local diffeo. Then global injectivity implies that the map is diffeo onto its image.

Comment: @Max that is written as part of my question too...